# custom filter for hiding the negative values

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a text box, I want to show nothing in the text box if the ng-model contains negative value, and I want to leave ng-model as it is. And it should not display the data if the data is negative value,If the value is negative then I want to show the empty in text box, but the ng-model should contain that negative value. I need a custom filter to achieve this functionality

[Plunker](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/5673/)

```
<input type = "text" ng-model="number"></input>
```

Comment: you can use the $watch

Answer (score 2):

[Filters can be added in AngularJS to format data.](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_filters.asp)

Now, if you are thinking to 'bind' `ngModel` with the text-box and want to apply filter on it (i.e. markup: `<input ng-model="number | nonNegative" />`), try-it yourself, you'll get the below error, when you check it in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/5676/)

> Error: Non-assignable model expression: number | nonNegative ()

When you want to show the values are below, using filter, you'll be able to do so.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('LoginController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.number = -10;
    $scope.number1 = -20;
    $scope.number2 = 30;
})
.filter('nonNegative', function(){
  return function(val){
     if(val >= 0) return val; else '';
  }
})
```

HTML:

```
Number: {{number | nonNegative}}
<br/>
Number1: {{number1 | nonNegative}}
<br/>
Number2: {{number2 | nonNegative}}
```

----EDIT-----
Even when you use `$watch`, the actual value will be different and the value in the textbox will be different.
Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/5677/)

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('LoginController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.number1 = -20;

  $scope.$watch('number1', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if(newVal < 0) newVal = '';
  })
})
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="LoginController">
    <input type = "text" ng-model="number1" />
    <input type="submit" ng-click="login()" value="Login" />
<br/>
Number1: {{number1 | nonNegative}}
</div>
```

The `number` field is having no value, as you see in the fiddle, but still the textbox displays negative value

Comment: by using the above code will it restrict showing the negative values in the screen? if yes will the ng-model contains the value

Comment: that's what the point is. You can't bind a single control having `ng-model` on it and filter applied over it to display the value as per your need.

Comment: If you use `$watch`, you can manipulate the value, but in that case, the model property will be updated as well. let me update the fiddle n provide it to you

Comment: Okay, it seems good, but how can I stop showing the negative values in the text box itself

Comment: @Paritosh  is it posible to show the `Number1: {{number1 | nonNegative}}` in the text box itself

Comment: is it posible to write this one as directive

Comment: I think yes, `directive` is well suitable at this place instead of `filter`