# how to convert filter to directive in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[This is my old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48619629/custom-filter-for-hiding-the-negative-values), where I want to filter out negatives numbers from an input filed:

```
<input type = "text" ng-model="number"></input>
```

In my old question, Paritosh given me the [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48620226/8495123), but I need to convert that code from filter to directive. How can I convert it into a directive?

```
app.filter('nonNegative', function(){
  return function(val){
     if(val >= 0) return val; else '';
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to just include ngmodel in directive

```
app.directive('myDirective', function(){
return{ 
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs,ngModel){
       // Your filter operation
       if(scope.number < 0)
         scope.number = 0;
    }
}
});
```

This will work when the element is loaded for the first time

Comment: will this value effect's to ng-model??

Comment: this directive is not calling, can you please provide me a simple plunker or fiddle with this directive calling

Comment: @VikashKumar [_looks like it wasn't clear enough_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48623961/angular-directive-is-not-calling)