# angular directive is not calling

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a angular directive and it is not calling when I typing on that field

**HTML**

```
  <input type="text" my-directive/>




   app.directive('myDirective', function(){
    return{ 
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs,ngModel){
           // Your filter operation
           if(scope.number < 0)
             scope.number = 0;
        }
    }
    });
```

Comment: can you explain why do you need a filter as a directive? (_instead of making hundreds new questions_)

Comment: I just don't want to display negative values in my text box and the ng-model should contain that negative value

Answer (score 1):

Try instead to check for if defined or not...

`undefined < 0 === false`

`if(!scope.number) {scope.number = 0;}`

But in general you need to define what you want to happen. If you need to access the ng-model then you need to use the ngModelController. Also add an ng-modal to the input. There is no hook...

One caveat to be aware of as well - type="text" is a string and not a number...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48619629/custom-filter-for-hiding-the-negative-values/48620226?noredirect=1#comment84237377_48620226 this is my old question, I need a directive like the filter that give  by Paritosh, Please help me on this

Comment: youre building a directve he is building a filter. probaby need to dig into the code a bit.

Comment: SO is a platform to help when you are stuck. Codementor is a platform to pay people to build your stuff ;)

Answer (score 0):

Angular directives have to be linked to  elements

If you want to include an input on it, should be in the template of the inner directive.

Answer (score -1):

```
  app.directive('numberOnly', function () {

  return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
          modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
              if (inputValue == undefined) return '';
              var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
              if (transformedInput != inputValue) {
                  modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                  modelCtrl.$render();
              }
              return transformedInput;
          });
      }
  };
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="mobile" ng-required="true" ng-model="mobile" number-only />
```

Comment: I deleted your code image. Please never post images of code. Always post code as text and format it properly, thank you.

Comment: I am not getting input value, alway I am getting input value as ""

Comment: @TomBrunberg How do you post html, My html was not visible  so added the image. user9130953 Use following html <input  type="text"  name="mobile" ng-model="mobile" number-only />

Comment: actually it is just hiding the -(minus) infront of the value but not it is hiding the negative value

Comment: twitch, sorry for messing around with your answer. The last line of html is the one you originally had in your post (I think). To just display html in your post, indent the html code 4 spaces, just as any code.

Comment: @TomBrunberg Thanks will keep that in mind. user9130953 the directive above allow user to added number to an input box others are remove if you want negative number to be replaced by 0 then add a check if inputValue < 0 then transformedInput = 0....